# Удалить пробелы с помощью trim()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

Подскажите как исполнить пожалуйста. Есть input добавления тегов, нужно удалять все пробелы из строки, а если пробелы есть  нельзя нажать на кнопку добавления тега. Я сделал таким способом но сказали сделать через trim() а у меня ничего не выходит

```
  const addTag = () => {
  const currentIndex = fields.length - 1;
  const currentValue = watch(`tags[${currentIndex}].name`, "");
  if (currentValue.search(/\s/) !== -1) {
    return [false, error()];
  }
  if (!currentValue) return;
  append("");
  console.log("TAGs: ", currentValue);
```

};

Comment: Попробуйте сравнивать длину строки до и после `trim()`.

Comment: Trim удалит только начальные и конечные пробелы